# Generador de colores de manera aleatoria en C

Tags: c, compilador, ccs, lenguaje-compilado

Qué tal? Necesito que me den una ayuda con esta duda, estoy haciendo un juego didáctico en Pic C Compiler el cual arranca escogiendo un color de tres y una vez hecha esa elección de color, se realizarían algunas condiciones específicamente para ese color. Una vez que se lleven a cabo las condiciones de manera correcta, se escoge un color distinto nuevamente y se realizan otras condiciones específicas para ese color y así con todos los colores. Hasta que no se cumplan las condiciones no se puede escoger otro color.
Lo que tengo hasta ahora es que si se escogen los colores de manera aleatoria pero no sabría como colocar las condiciones para cada color.
Desde ya graciaas

```
void main ()
{

// --- SELECCION RANDOM DE COLOR Y FIGURA ---
// Tenemos cuatro leds RGB, los cuales contienen tres colores cada uno.
  while(true)
  {
  color=rand()% (randmaxcol-randmincol+1) + randmincol;
  
  switch(color)
   {
      case 1: output_bit(PIN_B1, 0); break; // Color rojo
      case 2: output_bit(PIN_B2, 0); break; // Color verde
      case 3: output_bit(PIN_B3, 0); break; // Color azul
   }
   
 
  
     delay_ms(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! pero de que condiciones hablas?

Comment: Estoy haciendo un juego con piezas de colores, por lo que cada led rgb me indica que pieza y de que color debo presentar. pongo el ejemplo de una pieza verde: Una vez que inicia el programa y me indica un color, tiene que permanecer prendido y se enciende un sensor de color, el cual tiene que detectar una pieza de color verde. si se detecta otra de otro color, permanece encendido hasta que se presente una pieza verde, una vez que se lea el color esperado encienden unos sensores de movimiento que van a detectar cuando coloco la pieza que me indica el led en el inicio. +

Comment: hasta que un sensor de mov. en especifico no detecte el 1, no se puede cambiar de color. una vez que detecte el 1 arranca el mismo proceso nuevamente pero con otro color

Comment: Ese es tu ejercicio.. cual es el problema?